# Zsh completion: move into list selection on first tab

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

### Short Description

When I hit `<tab>` in zsh, I want the first completion candidate to be highlighted *immediately* instead of requiring me to hit `<tab>` a second time to focus the list.

### Example

Say I have a directory structure like this:

```
Projects/
  |
  +-- FooAwesome/
  |
  +-- FooAwesomeThings/
  |
  +-- FooBar/
```

If I'm in `Projects/` and I type `cd Foo<tab>`, zsh kindly presents me with a list of options.

[image: Zsh completion options]

However, in order to get into selection inside the list, I have to hit `<tab>` again before the first candidate gets highlighted.

[image: First item on list selected]

How could I get the first selection highlighted on the first time I hit `<tab>`?

### Current Configuration

```bash
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored _correct _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' expand prefix
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{[:lower:]}={[:upper:]}' 'm:{[:lower:][:upper:]}={[:upper:][:lower:]}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*'
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt %SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s

zstyle ':completion:*' file-list all
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}

zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''

zmodload zsh/complist
bindkey -M menuselect 'h' vi-backward-char
bindkey -M menuselect 'k' vi-up-line-or-history
bindkey -M menuselect 'j' vi-down-line-or-history
bindkey -M menuselect 'l' vi-forward-char
bindkey -M menuselect '^xi' vi-insert

zstyle :compinstall filename '/Users/ashton/.zshrc'
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

I'm not using a plugin manager like `oh-my-zsh` or anything. I'd prefer a "vanilla" solution if possible—i.e. pure zsh config without any fancy custom packages or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I remove `setopt menu_complete` from my configuration it stops jumping to the first item. I think you might need `setopt no_list_ambiguous` in conjunction with this too. `zshoptions(1)` says:

> `MENU_COMPLETE (-Y)`
>
> On an ambiguous completion, instead of listing possibilities or beeping, insert the first match immediately.  Then when completion is requested again, remove the first match and insert the second match, etc.  When there are no more matches, go back to the first one again. `reverse-menu-complete` may be used to loop through the list in the other direction. This option overrides `AUTO_MENU`.